# SELECT with prefix alias

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    alarms.*,
    prescriptions.id AS 'prescription_id'
FROM
    alarms
    INNER JOIN prescriptions ON alarms._prescription_id = prescriptions.id
WHERE
    DATE(date) = DATE(:date)
```

In this query I use the alias `prescription_id` for the column prescription.id (which is named `id`)

Now. What I need, is to prefix all the columns in my prescriptions table with the alias `prescription_column` (eg. `prescription_date` and `prescription_name`).

I was thinking if maybe there was an easier way to do it, than to just type in all the columns, of which i need an alias for, and so I come to you Stackoverflow, asking if any of you would know an easier way to do this?

Comment: This is not possible in standard SQL which does not have any meta-programming features, in fact; and SQLite's implementation is rather basic. Unfortunately you'll need to manually name every column in the output. Also you should avoid using the `*` symbol in SELECT statements because it makes query consumers brittle in the event of a schema change.

Comment: For stuff like this I usually use something like excel. It allows you to quickly edit your query. Especially when you have an sql formatter.

Comment: Point taken, I can see why it would actually be wiser to type out each column anyway.